# Visualization table sorting not works for am,pm time

Tags: google-visualization

I have created a Table using Google Visualization API. The Table Data has Time with am (or) pm. If i sort the column, it is not sorting time properly. If i use 24-hour time format , it sorts properly. I want to sort table column with am,pm time properly. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Populate Google visualization data table in Php like below.

**To Table Header:**

```
array('id'=>"ext","label"=>"Exit_time","pattern"=>"","type"=>"datetime")
```

**Add data to table:**

```
array("v"=>"Date(0, 0, 0,$t1[0],$t1[1],$t1[2])")
```

Here $t1[0]=hours,$t1[1]=minutes,$t1[2]=seconds